# Generating JSON files when using URL through Ajax in Python

Tags: python, json, ajax, web-scraping, url

I am trying to web-scarp Shazam. Someone already helped me understand that the url that I was passing into Beautiful soup is loaded through Ajax.

I am not to sure how what I need to use to generate the json files from the url's I pass?

I want to generate json files for many countries most shazamed songs.

The url from Shazam is:
https://www.shazam.com/charts/top-200/south-africa,

This is the json file generated on the global shazamed songs:
https://www.shazam.com/shazam/v3/en-US/US/web/-/tracks/world-chart-world

I am using python 3.

Thanks so much for the assistance

Answer (score 1):

You can query the api directly:

for South africa its: https://www.shazam.com/shazam/v3/en/NO/web/-/tracks/ip-country-chart-ZA?pageSize=200&startFrom=0

and you have to change the part that says `ip-country-part-ZA` for different countries. If i want charts from Norway i change it to `ip-country-part-NO`

so here is what i would do:

```
response = requests.get("https://www.shazam.com/shazam/v3/en/NO/web/-/tracks/ip-country-chart-ZA?pageSize=200&startFrom=0").json()
track_data = response["tracks"]
tracks = [f'{track["title"]} - {track["subtitle"]}' for track in track_data]
```

Comment: Thanks Bendik. How did you query it though? Sorry. I would just like to understand the full method.

Comment: I've updated my answer with code to get all songs in a list

Comment: Sorry, that part is good. I know how to make my way through the json file. I am interested in how you generated the json file from the shazam url. @6547224. How did you query that api directly?

Comment: I just looked in the network tab in chrome dev tools and found where the webiste fetched data